# How to cache third party API access in SQL database for a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, sql, api, caching

Is there any way to cache data for a WordPress plugin ? I have a ready one that uses third party API access to YouTube API V3 and I need to apply cache for both optimization and keeping the hits under the quota.

Supposing I have this function:

```
function popular_uploads() {
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=viewCount&part=snippet&channelId='. channel_id(). '&maxResults=5&key={key}&type=video';
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json_data = json_decode($json, false);
        foreach ( $json_data->items as $item ) {
            $id = $item->id->videoId;
            echo '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="auto" height="auto" 
                src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' . $id . '?rel=0&showinfo=1"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        }
}
```

How am I going to cache the data for sometime in a database ? I am really new to this process and I have looked it up and couldn't find a fix.

Thank you so much for assisting a beginner!

Regards.

**Edit:**

I have followed all steps found in [Simple PHP caching](http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/) article, the only difficulty I have is implementing the code below :

```
<?php
// Some query
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
  echo '<li><a href="view_article.php?id='.$r['id'].'">'.$r['title'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of [WordPress Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to store temporary, cacheable data.

This allows you to save a value, along with an amount of time that the value should be cached for. Here is an example of how this might work with your function:

```
function popular_uploads() {

    // Try to retrieve saved data from the cache
    $json_data = get_transient('my_unique_identifier');

    // If no saved data exists in the cache
    if ($json_data === false) {

        // Fetch new data from remote URL
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=viewCount&part=snippet&channelId='. channel_id(). '&maxResults=5&key={key}&type=video';
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json_data = json_decode($json, false);

        // Save the data in the cache, let it live for up to 1 hour (3600 seconds)
        set_transient('my_unique_identifier', $json_data, 3600);
    }

    foreach ( $json_data->items as $item ) {
        $id = $item->id->videoId;
        echo '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="auto" height="auto" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' . $id . '?rel=0&showinfo=1"
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }

}
```

By using the Transients API, you let WordPress decide the best way to store the values (either in the database, or in a cache of some kind). [From the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API):

> ...Transients are inherently sped up by caching
>   plugins, where normal Options are not. A memcached plugin, for
>   example, would make WordPress store transient values in fast memory
>   instead of in the database. For this reason, transients should be used
>   to store any data that is expected to expire, or which can expire at
>   any time. Transients should also never be assumed to be in the
>   database, since they may not be stored there at all.

Comment: It is WORKING !! I don't know how to thank you, you are the best !!

Comment: So, no need to create database tables and all that complicated stuff ?

Comment: Glad to hear it works great! That is correct, when you write set_transient() that tells WordPress to handle the creation of database or cache entries as needed and you don't have to think about it. WordPress will decide the best way to handle it based on what caching system is available on the server.

Comment: Thanks @bcole !
Tough I have another issue which is when the user changes the channel ID from the settings panel, the previous cached data keep appearing, here I use this code: 
`global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_ytio_%')" );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_timeout%_ytio_%')" );` ( all my transients are named ytio_xxxx ) Now I really want to put that into a function which boots when the input value is updated.. will proceed.
I thank you once again :)

Comment: There's a function already for that too; 

use `delete_transient( 'my_unique_identifier' );`

Comment: Important to use the function `delete_transient` because they may or may not get stored in the database, depending on if there is a better caching option available.

Comment: Yes I came across that function in the codex. I just have about 10 transients and I don't think listing them inside that functions separated by commas is a good practice. anyways the `$wpdb->query` works fine. will find a way to execute it when a setting is updated.

Comment: Alright then, in light of your new highlight, will use `delete_transient` , you never know if data are stored in db or somewhere else..